# How can I get a limit to the probability using the Maximal Kolmogorov's inequality?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I have that $\{Y_i\}_{i\geq 0}$ independent random variables with $E(Y_i)=0$ and $Var(Y_i)=1$ and exist $0<M<\infty$ such that $Y_i \in [-M,M]$, for all $i \geq 1$. I need to limit 
$$ P\left(\sup_{n \geq 1} |S_n|>k\right)$$
where $S_n=Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$.

I need to use the Maximal Kolmogorov's inequality and then prove that 
$$ \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty P\left(\sup_{n \geq 1} |S_n|>k\right) < \infty. $$
But I dont know how to limite the probability using this inequality. Some tips are also valid.

Comment: $E(Y_i^2) < \infty$ is redundant for two reasons

Comment: @mathworker21 :  I counted the reasons and indeed I found two.

Comment: Isn't the problem false though? Simple random walks on $\mathbb{Z}$ almost surely go arbitrarily far away from the origin. Do you mean $S_n = \frac{Y_1+\dots+Y_n}{n}$.